# How do I get the newest tag with Azure devops Rest Api?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to recover the newest tag in azure devops, for that I am using this Uri:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=tags/&api-version=5.1
```

This returns all tags. 
If I set the $top=1 parameter it returns the first label found which is the oldest.

So the question is;

Is there any way to get the newest one? 
Or do I have to download everything and get the last one by hand?

Is there another way to retrieve the tags?

Edit with my work around in PowerShell (I accept suggestions):

```
$uriGetTags = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=tags/&api-version=5.1'
$tags = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uriGetTags -Headers $Headers | ConvertFrom-Json 

#I Only wants the last element (the newest)
$tag = $tags.value.Get($tags.count-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, currently there is no out-of-the-box rest api to get the newest tag directly. The tags returned are sorted by the oldest at the top. Even in the Tags manage in the UI, it is also sorted by the oldest at the top. And there is no such parameter to get the newest one.

As a workaround , you can write a powershell script to traverse these returned results and then write host the last result.

Comment: I was thinking about that (a PowerShell) but, if I have many tags ... I didn't want to download a lot of data. I think they have not thought about it. Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe good to know (and incredibly stupid): Git tags are sorted ALPHABETICALLY rather than based on time of creation in AzDo. This becomes a huge problem if your repositories use semantic versioning schemes. E.g.: 1.4.39 will be followed by 1.4.4 rather than 1.4.40.